# Find index of object in an array of prototypes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mobile, prototype

I am creating an app using jQuery mobile and need to get the index of an object in an array of prototypes.

The object, call team, is as follows:

```
var team = function (teamname, colour, rss_url, twitter_url, website, coords) {
    this.teamname = teamname;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.rss_url = rss_url;
    this.twitter_url = twitter_url;
    this.website = website;
    this.location = coords;


};
```

And the array itself looks like:

```
var teamlist = [32];

teamlist[0] = new    team("Aberdeen","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");

teamlist[1] = new team("Celtic","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");

teamlist[2] = new team("Dundee","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");

teamlist[3] = new team("Dundee United","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");

teamlist[4] = new team("Hamilton Academical","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");

teamlist[5] = new team("Inverness Caledonian Thistle","#C01A1A","http://www.football365.com/aberdeen/rss", "https://twitter.com/aberdeenfc","http://www.afc.co.uk/","57�09?33?N�2�05?20?W");`
```

I need to be able to get the index of an object based on teamname. Ihad thought something along the lines of

```
var a = teamlist.indexOf(teamname: "Aberdeen");
```

That however, is obviusly not working.

Any suggestions are welcome - thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple index search by value algorithm.

```
function index_by_value(teamlist, teamname) {
 index = 0

 for (var i = 0; i < teamlist.length; i++) {
   if (teamlist[i].teamname == teamname) {
    index = i;
   }
 }

    return index;

}

index = index_by_value(teamlist, "Aberdeen"); // an example
```

Keep in mind though that if there are multiple objects in the list with the same teamname, it will return the last one's index. If it does not exist, the function will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough. You can use `Array.prototype.some`, have the index declared as a variable in lexical scope, and change it when a match occurs. Then return the index. Something like this:

```js
var data = [
  {x: '1'},
  {x: '2'},
  {x: '3'},
  {x: '4'}
]; // sample data

function findIndex (num) {
  // num is just the number corresponding to the object
  // in data array that we have to find
  var index = -1; // default value, in case no element is found
  data.some(function (el, i){
    if (el.x === num) {
      index = i;
      return true;
    }
  }); // some will stop iterating the moment we return true
  return index;
}

console.log(findIndex('3'));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var a = teamlist.filter(function(team) {
    return team.teamname = "Aberdeen";
});
```

It will produce new array of the teams object with the name of "Aberdeen". If you expect only one team the you need to take the first element from this array: `a[0]`.

Comment: There will only ever be one team found (all team names are unique). In your example above, how do I display the index of Aberdeen in the console? I am going to be using the index to reference the rss_url of the object found. Thanks

Comment: So do you have only team name as a string or you have team instance object you want to find corresponding index in array?

Comment: Each team has a teamname, colour, rss_url etc as shown above(sorry if Im not very good at explaining. I need to find the index of a specific team name e.g. "Aberdeen".  So ideally, when I ran the function to find "Aberdeen" in the array, I would get 0 as the result. This is so I can then use, for example, teamlist[0].rss_url . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getIndex(teamlist, teamname){
        for(var i = 0; i<teamlist.length; i++){
            if(teamlist[i].teamname == teamname){
                return i; // if found index will return
            }
        }
        return -1; // if not found -1 will return
    }

var a = getIndex(teamlist,"Aberdeen"); // will give a as 0
```